# Duplicate items in select box drop down laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have a select box that populates automatically from the database. My database table has a column(estatename) that contains items with similar names for example :

```
id | estate_cat_id |   estatename | Location |  Size

 1       1             Estate1      Location    One bedroom
 2       2             Estate2      Location    Two bedroom
 3       3             Estate1      Location    Three bedroom
 4       4             Estate2      Location    One bedroom
```

The estates drop down in my form displays all the estates names repeating the similar ones too. I do not want the drop down to contain duplicate estatenames. How can I avoid duplicate estatenames?

This is the method that populates the Estate box in my view :

```
public function findEstateName(Request $request){
      $data=House::select('Estate','id')->where('prod_cat_id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();
      return response()->json($data);//send this data to ajax success
  }
```

Comment: the problem seems to be on your database design. I think you can have a separate table for Estates

Comment: I will try that and see..